# access core functions script from anywhere in domain?

Tags: php, include, root

I have a `coreFunctions.php` file that contains most of my key functions and I put it at the root of my domain. Using `include()`, how do I access this from scripts located in lower directories? Example: I have a script in `http://domain.com/folder/index.php`, how would you access the `http://domain.com/coreFunctions.php` from that script?

Comment: you ought to put your core functions outside of the root of your domain, so that an access error doesn't render your code visible to malicious third parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/coreFunctions.php";
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [auto_prepend_file PHP setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
include("../coreFunctions.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

i havent tried `include` but tried `require` and i think `include` should work too for this.
just use
`require "http://domain.com/coreFunctions.php";`